# Как реализовать группировку и расчет среднего на основании информации из HashSet?

Tags: java, коллекции

Необходимо реализовать метод, который будет рассчитывать среднюю зарплату среди всех сотрудников; выводить список подразделений и среднюю зарплату каждого подразделения.

Использую коллекцию `Set<Employee> employeeList;`

Класс `Employee` имеет поля:

```
private long id;
private String fullName;
private Department department; (enum)
private BigDecimal salary;
```

Пытался сгруппировать таким образом, чтобы вывести список подразделений и среднюю зарплату, но в моем случае salary типа `BigDecimal` и метод `averaging` не подходит, т.к. он работает с `int, double, long,` а я пытаюсь найти среднее типа `BigDecimal`. Наверное такой подход реализовать до конца нет возможности? Тут либо вместо `BigDecimal` использовать другой тип или другим путем реализовывать метод. Как пытался делать:

```
public List<Employee> averageSalaryReport() {
    Map<Department, BigDecimal> averageSalaryDepartment = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,averagingInt(Employee::getSalary)));
    ...
}
```

P.s. Надеюсь, что более-менее понятно описал суть. Новичок в этом деле.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Так а саму проблему опишите. Раз пытались что-то делать, значит и результат есть. А то получается "не подходит" написали, а почему не подошло не описали. Какой результат Ваших стараний? Ошибка прилетает, или может считает не коректно?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как-то так ( без создания своего коллектора):

```
employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Employee::getDepartment,
                Collectors.mapping(Employee::getSalary, Collectors.toList())
        ))
        .forEach((key, list) -> {
            final BigDecimal total = list.stream()
                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
            BigDecimal average = total.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(list.size()));
            averageMap.put(key, average);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `averagingInt` реализуйте свой `Collector`, только для `BigDecimal`.
Реализацию `averagingInt` посмотреть легко, возьмите её за основу:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee(1, "vasya", Department.ONE, BigDecimal.valueOf(100)),
            new Employee(2, "fedya", Department.TWO, BigDecimal.valueOf(300)),
            new Employee(3, "cj", Department.MAIN, BigDecimal.valueOf(1100)),
            new Employee(4, "madonna", Department.TWO, BigDecimal.valueOf(500)),
            new Employee(5, "tatyana", Department.MAIN, BigDecimal.valueOf(200)),
            new Employee(6, "michael jackson", Department.ONE, BigDecimal.valueOf(500)),
            new Employee(7, "petro", Department.ONE, BigDecimal.valueOf(300))
    );

    Map<Department, BigDecimal> averageSalaryDepartment =
            averageSalaryReport(employees);

    System.out.println(averageSalaryDepartment);
}

public static Map<Department, BigDecimal> averageSalaryReport(List<Employee> employeeList) {
     return employeeList.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
                Collector.of(() -> new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO},
                            (a, t) -> { a[0] = a[0].add(t.getSalary()); a[1] = a[1].add(BigDecimal.ONE); },
                            (a, b) -> { a[0] = a[0].add(b[0]); a[1] = a[1].add(b[1]); return a; },
                            a -> (a[1].compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) ? BigDecimal.ZERO : a[0].divide(a[1], BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))));

}
```